# Computing the p-value of a test statistic converging to a standard normal

Tags: mathematical-statistics, p-value

We are asked to do a hypothesis test for two random variables,

X~Bernoulli(p1), Y~Bernoulli(p2),
Ho: p2<=p1, H1: p2>p1.

We are given the data for a realisation (x,y) and a test statistic T(X,Y) to compute on R for the given data.

We are also told the test statistic converges in distribution to a standard normal when p1=p2. Then we are asked to compute the p value.

I thought it was asking us to compute the probability that the standard normal is greater than the value obtained for the test statistic given the realisations, but normally when doing this to compute the p value you have to compute this with “given Ho”, but I am not sure where/how I would use this property here.

I am also not sure how to justify using a standard normal, is it enough to say "since we know the test statistic converges in distribution when p1=p2, we can use this to approximate the p value"?

Thanks!

Comment: Test statistic involves $\hat p_1 = X/n,$ which by CLT is approximately distributed as $\mathsf{Norm}(p_1, \sqrt{p_1(1-p_1)/n_1}),$ for $n_1$ sufficiently large. $SD(\hat p_1)$ can be approximated. Similarly for $\hat p_2.$ Under $H_0,$ $p_1 = p_2$ and you can find aprox distn of test statistic. Various tests estimate std error in different ways, use $H_0$ in different ways, and may or may not use a continuity correction. // For a detailed discussion of the normal dist'n of the test statistic, you'd have to say exactly which of several test statistics you're using.